# How to quote mathematical symbols in z3py expression for use in graphviz labels?

Tags: graphviz, z3py

I am using z3py to do some analysis and generate graphviz dot files with labels generated by z3py expression strings. but some symbols like > give graphviz some error.  e.g.

`digraph network { place0 [shape=record label="place |{[p0 > 0, p1 > 0]|[p0, p1]}|[]"];`

I would like it to be as follows

`digraph network { place0 [shape=record label="place |{[p0 \> 0, p1 \> 0]|[p0, p1]}|[]"];`

Is there a way in z3py to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing s.replace(">", "\>") and problem solved ;)